# Wordpress login page just redirects itself

Tags: wordpress, routes, wordpress-login

I have a wordpress blog that someone else on my team setup. It was working fine awhile ago, but no when we try to login with the correct credentials, the login page just redirects.

I go from here:

```
http://blog.lessonshark.com/wp-login.php
```

To this:

```
http://blog.lessonshark.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.lessonshark.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

Is this a routing issue or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you recently upgraded Wordpress? and is this happening in all browsers?

I've had this issue before.  Once was after an upgrade and after it redirected a couple times it let me in.  The second was an issue in the database with site url.  The link below will walk you through fixing the issue.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble#Site_URL_Redirecting

Comment: Thanks I'm looking into the code. Might be a db thing. We haven't upgraded in awhile.